# Graph Theory with Directed Graph and Dominance Order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

(a) Suppose four teams, the Aces, the Birds, the Cats, and the Dogs, play each
other once. The Aces beat all three opponents except the Birds. The Birds
lost to all opponents except the Aces. The Dogs beat the Cats. Represent the
results of these games with a directed graph.

[image]

(b) A dominance order is a listing of teams such that the ith team in the order
beats the (i + 1) st team. Find all dominance orders for part (a).

The dominance order that I found was ADCB but would I be able to have more than one dominance order? For example can DBAC be another dominance order?

Comment: Indeed. Nothing in the statement contradicts this possibility.

Comment: @Jsevillamol So DBAC would be the only possibility starting with D? So I have found a dominance order for A and D, now I have to try to find one for B and C correct?

Comment: It is not the only order - for example, DCBA is also a dominance order

Comment: @Jsevillamol Wouldn't DCBA be redundant to ADCB?

Comment: Note that starting with any team and following a loop counterclockwise will produce a dominance order.

Comment: Would a dominance order be ADBAC? If I'm correct this breaks the i+1 rule?

Comment: Typically a dominance order is an ordering on the vertices (in your case $\{A, B, C, D\}$) so you only want to use each vertex once.